# Can two accounts share the same game client with different licenses?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I have a PS4 with a Heavensward-licensed FFXIV account.  I'll be visiting a friend who also has a PS4 with a licensed FFXIV account, but they do not have Heavensward.

Will I be able to log into my account on their system?  And if so, I assume I would end up upgrading their client to Heavensward, so would they then be able to continue using their non-Heavensward account to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you registered your own PS4 copy to your Square Enix account, [you would have been prompted to link your PlayStation Network account to that Square Enix account](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/pr/start_ffxiv/ps3/has_account/), which is a required step for all PS3 and PS4 players. As such, as long as you log into your friend's PS4 with your own PSN account, you should be able to log into the game and play just fine.

According to @Troyen in the comments, as of version 3.26, you need to download approximately 3GB of additional data the first time you log into a Heavensward-enabled account on an existing install of the game that has previously only been used for ARR.

Comment: I do remember having to install a few extra gigs of stuff when I had ARR during the 3.1 era and upgraded to Heavensward, but I also saw the [disk space requirements were increased for ARR-only players in 3.2](http://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/topics/detail/bdd3156a32a13a8b7590e9a5e0aa542bcab14c7f).  Regardless, main concern would be not locking him out of playing his account.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem for him. Having an expansion registered to your account simply sets a flag that allows you to access the new content. If the expansion data is installed but you don't have the expansion registered, the server simply doesn't acknowledge it, and everything plays out as if you didn't have it installed. The only problem occurs when you have an expansion registered, but don't have the data installed on the system. In this case, if, and only if, you've logged out in an expansion area, you won't be able to log in until the expansion data is installed.

Comment: For the record, there's a 3GB download when logging into a HS account running the up-to-date 3.26 ARR client for the first time.